# Error in Context while adding custom system service

Tags: android, service

I have created a custom system service and have added in android source code.

I tested if the service has been successfully registered by **flashing the system and boot image and it's successful**.

So, I tried accessing the service I created from application side using the following code,

```
 SampleManager samplemanager = (SampleManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.SAMPLE_SERVICE);
```

When I code this line , there is a error in 'Context.SAMPLE_SERVICE' . It says must be one of **'Context.Power_service,Context.Window_service etc'**.

I have modified the following files under frameworks/base for service,

```
  Android.mk
  core/java/android/app/SystemServiceRegistry
  core/java/android/content/context.java
  preloaded-classes
  services/core/ Android.mk
  services/core/jni/ Android.mk
  services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java
  core/java/android/content/context.java 
  services/core/jni/ onload.cpp
```

Apart from these files, I have created my own files required to create service and I have checked these links too,

[How to add custom system service name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321487/how-to-add-custom-system-service-name-to-servicename-stringdef)
   [Context error in system service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102750/context-error-of-custom-system-service)

As per the link, I have checked in all the files but everything seems fine. 
Any idea where the problem would be? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.